# How to add a Autofill filter in FilterBar

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to implement filters using SAPUI5 FilterBar. I want to add a field which works like a dropdown filter only when you type something in it. When you put the cursor, it should not show any results, but as you start typing something, the matching results should show up in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ogJWFfpoMsZXPpS9yf65?p=preview)

You could use a **[Input](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input/)** object in the **filterGroupItems** aggregation of the [FilterBar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar/) control.

> **Note:** The filterItems aggregation is deprecated as of version **1.48**

```html
<fb:FilterBar id="filterBar">
    <fb:filterGroupItems>
        <fb:FilterGroupItem 
            groupName="GroupExample" 
            name="regionGroup" 
            label="Example" 
            visibleInFilterBar="true">
            <fb:control>
                    <Input showSuggestion="true">
                        <suggestionItems>
                            <core:Item key="001" text="Russia"/>
                            <core:Item key="002" text="America"/>
                            <core:Item key="003" text="Australia"/>
                            <core:Item key="004" text="Germany"/>
                        </suggestionItems>
                    </Input>
            </fb:control>
        </fb:FilterGroupItem>
    </fb:filterGroupItems>
</fb:FilterBar>
```

Which produces:

[image: gif]

Be sure to add the `visibleInFilterBar="true"` attribute if you want your input field to be visible without having to add it in the *Filters* prompt.

---

If you want to add the `Input` items dynamically, add an aggregation binding to the `<items>`. 
To do that, change the `Input` control as follows:

```html
<Input suggestionItems="{path: '/dropdownData'}" showSuggestion="true">
    <suggestionItems>
        <core:Item key="{key}" text="{text}"/>
    </suggestionItems>
</Input>
```

And set the model according to your datasource (here it's a `JSONModel`) in the controller:

```
onInit: function() {
    this.oModel = new JSONModel("/data.json");
    var oView = this.getView();
    oView.setModel(this.oModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I don't want a traditional dropdown filter. I want something like an empty field, without any dropdown arrow icon. When I start typing, it should show the list of available options starting with the entered keyword, but when i put the cursor on the filter initially, it should now show anything.